# Pull variable name from $_GET[] array

Tags: php, variables, post, get, boolean

What I want to do is pull everything after the `?` query like a $_GET. I know I can use `$_GET['test']` to pull `?test=true` but what if I just want to pull `?true` or `?false` I want to hold everything after the `?` in a variable. I could probably use `$_SERVER` get pull the url then chop it up into what I need, but that just seemed like the long / incorrect way of doing it. Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: So, you simply want to prepend a ?

Comment: `?true` or `?false` is not "everything after the `?`"  Do you mean you would want `test=true` or `test=false` in a variable?  Because in that case, yes, you would want to use $_SERVER.

Comment: @Corbin I want to pull true or false, without them having to type `test=` in the url. I want the user to be able to type `?true` or `?false` and get what they need.

Comment: You might be able to get away with array_key_exists('true', $_GET) or the same thing for 'false'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get everything after the `?` (called the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)) from the variable:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. There a lot of rarely used but highly useful $_SERVER variables which you can find at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php